# Why my Regex is not detecting phone numbers written in certain patterns?

Tags: regex

I have a regex to check phone numbers in a text. Please check below.

```
(\d[\s-]?)?[\(\[\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\)\]\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}
```

This regex works fine but it does not work well if I write it this way.

1. Ex 1: 088 11 22 458
2. Ex 2: +1 88 11 22 458

How can I modify the regex to fix this bug?

Comment: What about `(?:\+?\d[\s-]?)?[([\s-]{0,2}\d{2,3}[)\]\s-]{0,2}(?:\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}|\d{2}[\s-]?\d{2}[\s-]?\d{3})`? See https://regex101.com/r/NAgVzN/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an optional `+` at the start, allow two or three digits in the area code and add an alternative to match two double digits and then a chunk of three digits in the end:

```
(?:\+?\d[\s-]?)?[([\s-]{0,2}\d{2,3}[)\]\s-]{0,2}(?:\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}|\d{2}[\s-]?\d{2}[\s-]?\d{3})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NAgVzN/1). *Details*:

- `(?:\+?\d[\s-]?)?` - an optional occurrence of **an optional `+`**, a digit and then a whitespace or a hyphen
- `[([\s-]{0,2}` - zero, one or two `(`, `[`, whitespace or hyphen chars
- `\d{2,3}` - **two or three digits**
- `[)\]\s-]{0,2}` - zero, one or two `)`, `]`, whitespace or hyphen chars
- `(?:\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}|\d{2}[\s-]?\d{2}[\s-]?\d{3})` - either of

  - `\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}` - three digits, an optional whitespace or `-`, four digits
  - `|` - or
  - `\d{2}[\s-]?\d{2}[\s-]?\d{3}` - two digits, an optional whitespace or `-`, two digits, an optional whitespace or `-`, three digits

You might also think of adding numeric boundaries to disallow matches that have other digits on the left (with the negative `(?<!\d)` lookbehind) and right (with the negative `(?!\d)` lookahead):

```
(?:\+?(?<!\d)\d[\s-]?)?[([\s-]{0,2}(?<!\d)\d{2,3}[)\]\s-]{0,2}(?:\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}|\d{2}[\s-]?\d{2}[\s-]?\d{3})(?!\d)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NAgVzN/2).

Answer (score 1):

I would use this regex:
`[\+\(\[]?\d[\(\[\s-]?\d[\s-]?\d[\)\]\s-]?\d[\s-]?\d[\s-]?\d[\s-]?\d[\s-]?\d[\s-]?\d[\s-]?\d`

It allows to use delimiters in any place.
Sometimes phone numbers are delimiter so that it will be easier to remember them.

For example:

- 088 111-2-111
- (088)11-22-33-4